# In Next js App, user uploaded image via API and it returns me Images in array, How to embed those image into CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, next.js, file-upload, ckeditor5

***Basically instead of using CKEditor to upload image i use my own api to upload image***

Whenever user in my website upload any image, i call API and posting those images to that API, it safely uploads images and returning me URL which is uploaded in Public Domain,
Below object returned by API,

```
{
    "uploadedUrls": [
        "http://example.com/community/question/insta.jpg",
        "http://example.com/community/question/pin.jpg"
    ]
}
```

and In my next js website the function behind API is working like this

```
  const handleUpload = async () => {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload'); 
  if (fileInput && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const files = Array.from(fileInput.files);

    files.forEach((file, index) => {
      formData.append("files", fileInput.files[index], file.name);
    });

    formData.append("folderName", "community/question");

    try {
      const uploadImage = await communityDTO.uploadImage(formData);
      if (uploadImage) {
        if (typeof uploadImage.uploadedUrls === 'string') {
            uploadImage.uploadedUrls = [uploadImage.uploadedUrls];
        }
        console.log(uploadImage); //This is also working very good
        uploadImage.uploadedUrls.map((item)=>(
            setInputBody(inputBody + "\n" + 
                <img className="my-2" src={item} alt={"Image " + item} />
            ))
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  } else {
    console.error('No files selected');
  }
};
```

In my console i get perfect success result from `console.log(uploadImage)`

And my CKEditor looks like this

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    data={inputBody}
    onChange={(event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    setInputBody(data); //inputBody is useState hook
    }}
    config={{
    toolbar: {
        items: [
        "undo",
        "redo",
        "|",
        "bold",
        "italic",
        "blockQuote",
        "link",
        "numberedList",
        "bulletedList",
        "|",
        "heading",
        ],
        shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true,
    },
    placeholder: "Write your Answer...",
    }}
/>
```

Everything is working fine and let me show u how inputBody i have declared
`const [inputBody, setInputBody] = useState("");`

Whenever i upload image the image should be embedded in CKEditor even if i upload Multiple images...

i am updating inputBody like below code when API returns successfully image uploading

```
uploadImage.uploadedUrls.map((item)=>(
   setInputBody(inputBody + "\n" + 
      <img className="my-2" src={item} alt={"Image " + item} />
   ))
);
```

But the result i am getting is just like below image

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li3WO.png)

The result i get is like `[object Object]` instead of embedding image

> (Wow, Now i realised how stackoverflow is working with image uploading like this `[description](imageurl)`), It would be cool if CKEditor free version supports like this, idk if it actually supports if yes then please suggest me, but please help me with my above code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error: Solved**

I solved it by my own, the thing i modified is just created instance of ckeditor by useRef hook, i already tried it but it wasn't working so i did not mentioned earlier...

**The below code provided by chatGPT but still don't know it was not working**

```
const editor = editorRef.current.editor; // Access CKEditor instance from the ref
  uploadImage.uploadedUrls.forEach(url => {
   editor.model.change(writer => {
      const imageElement = writer.createElement('image', {
         src: url // Set the source URL for the image
      });
      editor.model.insertContent(imageElement);
   });
});
```

**but the new code i modified by my self within instance of editor**

```
const editor = editorRef.current.editor; // Access CKEditor instance from the ref

   uploadImage.uploadedUrls.forEach(url => {
      editor.model.change(writer => {
         editor.setData( `${inputBody} \n <img src=${url} alt=${url} />` );
   });
});
```

Above code is working very well but i think it's inappropriate use of writer
but still it's working, so i am not going to touch this code now...

> Thankyou StackOverflow